# Find input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems JQuery has some magic/nuances for using **.find** method for input element or some sophisticated descendants (or I am blind).
This is my JS code:

```
<div id="edit_lists_div">
  <div style="width: 100%; margin-bottom:5px">&nbsp;
  <button value="" style="display: none;" id="edit_lists_div_btn1">Btn1</button>
  <button value="" style="display: none;" id="edit_lists_div_btn2"
  disabled="disabled">Btn2</button>
  <button value="" style="display: none;" id="edit_lists_div_btn3"
  disabled="disabled">Btn3</button>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 210px; overflow: auto;">
  <table class="my_grid" id="edit_lists_div_table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <th width="30"></th>
          <th style="display: none;">id</th>
          <th width="100">Title</th>
          <th width="25">Some field 1</th>
          <th style="display: none;">some_property</th>
          <th>Some field 2</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <caption>Lists</caption>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td property_name="">
          <input row_selector="true" type="checkbox">
          </td>
          <td style="display: none;" property_value="157" property_name="id">157</td>
          <td property_value="List1" property_name="title">List1</td>
          <td property_value="4" property_name="subscribers_count">4</td>
          <td style="display: none;" property_value="9867,9869,9871,9868"
          property_name="subscribers">9867,9869,9871,9868</td>
          <td property_value="New" property_name="status">New</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

All I want to get the *input* field

```
<input row_selector="true" type="checkbox">
```

and manage it somehow. But **.find** can not find it! Here is what I do:

```
var tmp = $("#edit_lists_div").find("tbody");
var div_inputs = tmp.find("input"); // it is empty!
```

What is the problem here?

**UPDATE 1:** Note, the solution is still not found here. I've choosed already correct answer but unselected it because it became not workable in my app context. I mean this answer:

```
var tmp = $("#edit_lists_div").find("tbody");    
var div_inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#edit_lists_div');
```

was workable just for the FIRST Firebug debugging. Than I had empty/not_found JQuery object again.

The same story is for this code:

```
var tmp = $("#edit_lists_div").find("tbody");    
var div_inputs = $('input', '#edit_lists_div');
```

for the first single time it worked. But was broken after second try. What a mysticism here?!

**UPDATE 2:** As for possible problem at my handler... it's not! I've checked this code for this case:

```
$.ajax({
url : getUrl(),
dataType : "json",
success : function(data) {
   // my code goes here and still can't get input element!
  }
});
```

**UPDATE 3:** If it matter what for I need these inputs:

```
div_inputs.each(function() {
// some business logic with found inputs goes here
});
```

Comment: Your code should work, put it within document ready handler.

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/vEgda/

Comment: If you will comment console.log the result will be the same :)

Comment: That doesn't make sense, if console.log outputs the result, it means that it works.

Comment: You can also target it directly with `$("input[row_selector]")` or $("input[row_filter='true']")`  And like others are suggesting, make sure it is wrapped inside your document ready handler.

Comment: @MichaelZ, I'm not really sure what you mean. It works if I comment out the console.log statements and add and alert instead.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it's empty, are you expecting something to return, other than the element? It is after all a checbox, it's usually either checked or it's not ?

Comment: I mean it empty or not found, i.e. I can't see that JQuery object was retrieved in Firebug

Comment: @undefined If it outputs some that doesn't mean we have found JQuery object after .find method invocation

Comment: @EliGassert Can you elaborate please this moment. This code is invoked after user press some UI element. Is this that case?

Comment: Michael I think you need to update your question to show more of your code. Show the click event handler that calls that code, and perhaps create your own jsfiddle demo to show your code _not_ working in the context that you are using it. Otherwise we're just going around in circles because, as everybody has pointed out, there's nothing wrong with what you've shown above (as long as it runs after the document is parsed, which it should be if it is in response to a user clicking as you mentioned in a comment below - assuming the click handler itself works).

Comment: @MichaelZ I don't understand your question.  I was just saying that you can select on elements with more than class and id.  In my example, I'm selecting on inputs with the row_selector attribute set; or in the second example, explicitly looking for inputs with the row_selector attribute set to the value of true.  This would bypass the need to iterate the DOM hierarchy (find) to get to the element you want.

Comment: @EliGassert Oh, sorry my question was regarding second part of your answer regarding "wrapping inside document ready handler". Do not clearly understand it. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @nnnnnn I think it is not needed to show more of mine code because I have solution already from _adeneo_ . But I still do not understand what was wrong with my approach... :(

Comment: See answers below.  If you're not wiring up your click event handler in document ready (`$(function() { ... })`) then you might be binding it too early, thus your handler isn't actually being called.

Comment: @EliGassert  I am sure my handler is called because I debug it with Firebug

Comment: @nnnnnn Please see my second update. I think this is enough to see all the picture.

Comment: Could you update your update to show the entire Ajax success function with the problem code in place? And please confirm how you know that the success function is being called at all.

Comment: 1) I sure success is being call since I use debug at Firebug. 2) The content of success function of ajax call is exactly what is posted at my question and was demonstrated on Fiddle multiple times.

Comment: Surely there's more than just those two lines, because those two lines declare and set the `div_inputs` variable and then don't do anything with it. And because it is a _local_ variable you can't be using it anywhere else - so please show the whole function as it is in your real (non-working) code.

Comment: So what? What can I do with it if it is not found? But if it is matter next it has _div_inputs.each(function() {...});_ code for iterate all found inputs with further business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the solution is found. It was not in JQuery. It was in my app architecture. I had *async* **$.ajax** invocation before my JS code. On *success* function it created my table but as you understand I've tried to access this table elements before success method processing so before they were created!

Hope it will help some one. Beware of AJAX!

Answer (score 0):

I'd search for a checkbox within the table, as the table has an ID and should be easy to find, and there is only one checkbox :

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#edit_lists_div_table').prop('checked',true);
});
```

Comment: Did you wrap it in a DOM ready function, and you are sure the tbody element is outputted correctly in the browser etc?

Comment: 1) There can be more than one checkbox. Is your solution still correct? 2) I do not really know about DOM ready fun - this code is invoked after user click some UI element. Is this that case?

Comment: If there can be more than one checkbox inside the same table, you need something to tell them apart. An ID would be the best, but worst case you can select by index using `first()`, `last()`, `eq()` etc. If the click function works, so should the selector for the checkbox, if it exists.

Comment: This solution is WORK for me! So what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Open the console and check the outputted HTML in the elements view. Sometimes the browser will output tbody elements in strange places if it's somehow missing etc, and I normally don't use tbody as a selector as expierence has shown that there could be more of them then you think there is. It's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Well thanks but it seems _tbody_ is not the problem. Even this one doesn't work: _var tmp = $("#edit_lists_div").find("input");_

Comment: Could be just faulty code, are you absolutely definetively sure you have closed the `#edit_lists_div`, or that you have'nt gotten a closing statement to many in there before the table etc.

Comment: **You are actually missing `<` in the closing button elements**, so those are'nt closed, and that's probably the issue. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QYTgP/1/)

Comment: No, sorry that was just my copy-past mistake. The real code is OK regarding this. So this is NOT that case. More over (I'm afraid to say this), your code became unworkable too. I'm sure I've one time (when you post it in first) it was workable in my app context. But after this it hasn't any effects just like mine :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do away with `.find()` and chain your selectors instead:

```
 var $checkbox = $('#edit_lists_div tbody input');
```

Comment: @MichaelZ sorry, I missed the Fork button. Here's the actual code from this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hKn2J/ So, what is this code *not doing* that you want it to do? It's definitely making a jQuery object that contains the checkbox; please explain why that is not sufficient and we'll all have a better understanding of how to help you.

Comment: @apsillers This code has the same results with commented and uncommented _console.log_ so do not prove anything!

Comment: @MichaelZ The JavaScript console is certainly different when you comment out the line. I'm not what else you expect to be different when you call `console.log`. Try using `alert` instead of `console.log` if you don't know how to get to the JS console in your browser.

Comment: @chamila_c - Why would this work if `.find()` doesn't? Either both should work or neither.

Comment: @apsillers OK, alerts version is the prove! But why it doesn't work in my code context?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you are having.  The code you posted works fine on jsfiddler.net:

http://jsfiddle.net/BstRW/

// including formatted code is that stackoverflow is happy with my jsfiddle link.

```
var tmp = $("#edit_lists_div").find("tbody");
var div_inputs = tmp.find("input"); // it is empty!
alert(div_inputs.attr("type"));
```

Comment: Hmmm.. indeed your link has workable code. But why my code in my app not? :)